# The meaning of "get off" in Foxy's song

Tags: lyrics

I am listening Foxy's [*Get off*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGajlQvuwHU). The lyrics is as following.
**I am wondering what the idiom "get off" mean at here?**
I know that "get off" is used to meaning "to leave or to descend from a vehicle".
But it seems to be weird if I explain the idiom as leaving from a car at here.

Pretty ladies are at our discretion
So we can get off
We keep under the sheets with two lovelies
So we can get off

Sly look that we keep the promise, ladies
And make me get off
Take it from girls with our imagination
So we can get off

Call me up at your place, I can love you crazy
In the heat you will understand
Danger and excitement, that's what makes a lady
Find out what she wants in a man

To get off, to get off, to get off, to get off
To get off, to get off, to get off, to get, get off

Lookin' through that dress that drive me crazy and makes me get off
Sensuality excites my mind, it makes get off
If I were you I'd get a good perspective on how to get off
Love me wild and love me crazy, so we can get off

Call me up at your place, I can love you crazy
In the heat you will understand
Danger and excitement, that's what makes a lady
Find out what she wants in a man

To get off, to get off, to get off, to get off
To get off, to get off, to get off, to get, get off

Get off

So get off to get off, to get off, to get, get off
Get off to get off, to get off, get off
So get off, get off, to get off, to get, get off
Get off to get off, get off, get off

To get off, to get off, to get off, to get, get off
Get off, get off, get off, to get off
Get off to get off, get off, get, get off
Get off, get off, so get off, just get off
Get off, get off, get off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Get off" can mean a multitude of [different things](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_off) in English. In this context it's slang (generally British) for having sex.

Comment: Maybe in this context not so much "have sex" as "attain an orgasm".

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "get off" is a shorthand form of the (raunchy) phrase "get your rocks off", where "rocks" are testes, and getting them off means achieving orgasm. It's well-known slang on both sides of the Atlantic.

The shorthand form of the phrase was famously celebrated in Prince's hit song of the same name: